# How to disable modal closing when click on background in grapejs source editor?

Tags: modal-dialog, grapesjs

I created modal in [grapesjs](https://grapesjs.com/) to edit source code with editor modal. But when I am selecting text and release the button outside the modal, it will close without save.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Check documentation of [grapesjs modal](https://grapesjs.com/docs/api/modal_dialog.html#modal). There is link to configuration of modal behavior.

Just disable **backdrop** into editor init configuration.

```js
const editor = grapesJS.init({
  modal: {
    backdrop: false
  },
  // rest of configuration
});
```